# How to call a Controller and Action from HTML button in Cakephp?

Tags: cakephp

may be what i am trying to do is not correct, i just want to know if it is possible to call a controller and action from Html button in Cakephp.
something like:

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" title="Click to Deactivate" value="Make In-Active" onClick="location.href='<("Controller", "Action")>'" >
```

I just want to create an Html button which redirects to a controller and action.

Comment: Why wouldn't you jut use an `<a>` tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code:
It may be not 100% right, but it work

```html
<input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" title="Click to Deactivate" value="Make In-Active" onClick="javascipt:window.location.href='<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('controller'=>'controller','action'=>'action')) ?>'" >
```